# Image processing in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I want to do image processing in PHP. Any one can tell me what to do, what to install and what to configure and how to configure? I have heard about GD.

Comment: i think you will need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: more specific? from where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and follow the steps described there.

Comment: My dear I can also search this link. But why people come on this forum to find the understandable ways which are not defined in documentations.

Comment: Well, then, you could have at least written that you don't want to use this library, and why. It is obvious that people will point you to the default library if you ask such an open question. At least describe what you want to do and why the GD library isn't good enough for you.